# Node.js + MongoDB : MongoError: cursor killed or timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cursor

When finding a lot of documents and iterating over them using `cursor.nextObject`, one by one, the callback eventually returns undefined result and error `MongoError: cursor killed or timed out`. Whole error message is:

```
[MongoError: cursor killed or timed out] 
name: 'MongoError', 
message: 'cursor killed or timed out'
```

How to avoid the cursor to be killed?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mongodb's official doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findhttps://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find), the optional param `timeout` can be set to `false`.

```
db.collection('mycollection').find({}, {timeout:false}, function(err, cursor) {
    if (!err) {
         // Iterate safely on your cursor here
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: As per the document you refer to this is already the default: `timeout {Boolean, default:false}, specify if the cursor can timeout.`