# Meteor: Exception in setTimeout callback: MongoError: cursor killed or timed out

Tags: meteor

I get this error in Meteor:
`Exception in setTimeout callback: MongoError: cursor killed or timed out`

According to the answer here:
[Node.js + MongoDB : MongoError: cursor killed or timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856321/node-js-mongodb-mongoerror-cursor-killed-or-timed-out)

I can set `timeout: false` to stop this from happening when using the MongoDB shell, but how do I do this in Meteor?

Comment: Could you provide some more information (what are you trying to do?) and some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: cursor killed or timed out - Meteor timeout settings ineffective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480193/mongoerror-cursor-killed-or-timed-out-meteor-timeout-settings-ineffective)