# MongoError: cursor killed or timed out - Meteor timeout settings ineffective

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My Meteor 1.2.1 program threw `MongoError: cursor killed or timed out` in a `find().forEach()` loop, so i found [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#closure-of-inactive-cursors) that says this code prevents that:

```
var myCursor = db.users.find().noCursorTimeout()
```

However, the [driver docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/drivers/) and my Meteor say that method doesn't exist: `Object [object Object] has no method 'noCursorTimeout'`

Mongo autoReconnect is [enabled by default](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/425#issuecomment-10980296) and didn't help, nor did the [Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongoerror-cursor-killed-or-timed-out/8088), or even `.find({}, {timeout:false})` according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856321/node-js-mongodb-mongoerror-cursor-killed-or-timed-out#comment63279533_30856322).

2016-07-20 11:21:37 Update started

2016-07-20 11:37:21 Exception while invoking method 'updateCollections' MongoError: cursor killed or timed out

Maybe Meteor got confused by the failed SOAP call at 2016-07-20 09:34:57?

```
  "error": {
    "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT"
  },
```

Comment: Do you think that `maxTimeMS` method of the cursor object would help? Have you tried it?

Comment: `cursor.maxTimeMS(5000)` results in `Object [object Object] has no method 'maxTimeMS'`. MongoDB server 3.2 on Windows 10 understands it, but Meteor 1.2.1 doesn't. versions file says mongo@1.1.3 so i'll try to update that.

Comment: Re-adding the mongo package keeps Meteor version mongo@1.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `maxTimeMS` would help in this case you can access it by working with `rawCollection` object instead of the Meteor collection itself.

It's quite simple:

```
var rawCollection = Meteor.users.rawCollection();
var cursor = rawCollection.find({}).maxTimeMS(5000);
var myData = fetchCursor(cursor);
```

Where `fetchCursor` is a simple fiber-aware helper function that can be implemented like this:

```
var fetchCursor = Meteor.wrapAsync(function fetchCursor (cursor, cb) {
  cursor.toArray(cb);
});
```

Though, I am not sure if this method is exactly what you're looking for.

**Edit**

If you don't need the entire array of documents but you want to process each one of them independently it may be better to use `each` instead of `toArray`, e.g.

```
var fetchCursor = Meteor.wrapAsync(function fetchCursor (cursor, cb) {
  cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (!doc) return cb(null, { done: true }); // no more documents
    // do something with the document ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Won't that be memory-heavy? How do i do a `cursor.forEach` with that?

Comment: `myData.forEach()` works as it only contains small dictionaries.

Comment: Or not: `FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory` @ `AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:168`. No timeout up 'til then, though.

Comment: Instead of `toArray` you can use `each`.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I've added an example with `each` as you suggested.